# What word can be used to describe a construct (such as childhood) that changes over time and space

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Any help much appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You've given us very little to go on, however. Please see the guidance for [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). If you are new to Stack Exchange, I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how the site works.

Comment: Perhaps 'elastic' concepts. It would be helpful if you could add a sentence with a blank for the work you are looking for.

Comment: Isidore of Seville said: "The grammarians tell us that all words are ambiguous." Polysemic is a more recent term for a word that has several connotations.